# Codeigniter pagination URLs to be start with ?page=1 and so on

Tags: codeigniter, url, pagination, query-string

I have created my website in Codeigniter framework and want to update my pagination URL for a particular page not for whole website. Below the current URLs patterns which are working

```
https://www.example.com/city/2
https://www.example.com/city/hotel-with-air-conditioning.html/2
https://www.example.com/locality/hotels-in-dwarka.html/2
https://www.example.com/locality/5-star-hotel-in-dwarka.html/2
https://www.example.com/city/5-star-hotels-in-newdelhi.html/2
https://www.example.com/locality/hotel-with-air-conditioning-in-dwarka.html/2

Now I want to change them all above to as shown below:

https://www.example.com/city?page=2
https://www.example.com/city/hotel-with-air-conditioning.html?page=2
https://www.example.com/locality/hotels-in-dwarka.html?page=2
https://www.example.com/locality/5-star-hotel-in-dwarka.html?page=2
https://www.example.com/city/5-star-hotels-in-newdelhi.html?page=2
https://www.example.com/locality/hotel-with-air-conditioning-in-dwarka.html?page=2
```

I have used $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE; before initialize pagination method,

After making changes I got "&per_page=/2"  but not what I need. Also suggest what should I pass in $config['uri_segment'] as I do not want to pick page number from segment but from the query parameter ?page = X where X will be an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set a uri_segment when using the page_query_string.

To get the page=1 instead of per_page you should use the query_string_segment config, like so:

```
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
```

That extra / on your url its probably because you have a base url set with it. Try and remove it.

Also you might try and replace every occurrence of '&page=/' with '?page='.

Comment: Hi marcogmonteiro, 
Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to change $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page' now instead of "per_page" it is showing "page".  But how can I get rid of "&page=/2" or "&per_page=/3" and so on. I want the URL to be "?page=2" or "?page=3" and so on.

Is codeigniter pagination has any configuration so that I can change "&" to "?"  also able to remove "/"

Comment: @ashokostech I think that has to do with the fact that normally that kind of pagination method is used when you're not using your url like site.com/controller/method/ but when you're using it like http://example.com/index.php?c=test&m=page&per_page=20 so that assumes that the pagination will be the last query string you're doing, not the first one. I think to solve that part you can set your base pagination url to be foo.com? instead of foo.com. As for your / problem I would need more information. Please post your entire controller method so I can test it on my side.

Comment: actually I got it fixed by replacing every occurrence of '&page=/' with '?page=' without changing base url and it is working fine...

Comment: how to replace every occurrence of `'&page=/'` with `'?page='.`

Comment: Remove all links you might have that end with /

Answer (score 1):

I created a paginate helper that I use throughout. There's a little math to do to figure out how many total pages you have, but this should work.

```
<?php
function paginate($pagecount, $currentpage, $baseurl, $params = array()) {

    //var_dump($params);
    $param_parts = array();
    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        $param_parts[] = $key . '=' . $param;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="text-center">
    <?php
    $left_ellipsis = false;
    $right_ellipsis = false;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {

        if ( ($i < 4) || ($i > $pagecount - 3) || ($i > $currentpage - 3 && $i < $currentpage + 3) ) {

            if ($i == $currentpage) {
                ?>
                <span class="btn btn-sm disabled"><?php echo $i; ?></span>
                <?php
            } else {
                $urlout = array(
                    'currentpage=' . $i
                );
                $urlout = implode('&',$param_parts);
                if ($urlout != '') {$urlout = '&' . $urlout;}
                ?>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>?page=<?php echo $i; ?><?php echo $urlout; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            if ($currentpage > 6 && !$left_ellipsis) {
                $left_ellipsis = true;
                echo '<span class="ellip-block">...</span>';
            }
            if ($currentpage < $pagecount - 5 && $i > $currentpage && !$right_ellipsis) {
                $right_ellipsis = true;
                echo '<span class="ellip-block">...</span>';
            }
        }
        //echo $pagecount; 
    }
    ?></div><?php
}
?>
```

I named the helper file paginate_helper.php and to use it simply add it to any view.

The `$params` variable simply gets the array of the parameters that are passed in via "get".

```
<?php paginate($page, $cur, $url, array('q' => $q)); ?>
```

Might be helpful. Feel free to update and distribute.